# How do I install (anything) on debian: 'apt is unknown instruction' in Dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile, debian, wget, apt, apt-get

**How do I install (anything) on debian: 'apt is unknown instruction' in Dockerfile**

If I search: [**how to install wget on debian**]

I get articles that say:

`$sudo apt install wget`

---

So I try to do that in Docker:

```
FROM debain
apt install wget
```

and I get this error

```
/full/path/to/current/working/directory                          
[+] Building 0.1s (2/2) FINISHED                                                                                                  
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                         0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 102B                                                                                         0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                            0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                              0.0s 
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: dockerfile parse error line 2: unknown instruction: 
                                                                                                                                  
APT                                                                                                                               
/full/path/to/current/working/directory
```

--

**what could be the problem here?**

Comment: "apt" is not a docker command.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `RUN` instruction, like this:

```
FROM debian
RUN apt install wget
```